# Is there a way to make approximation outputs in to a list?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I am trying to write a code (python) that uses the Babylonian square root equation by usimg a while loop to approximate square root until error is less than an epsilon value and I am trying to print the approximations in the form [x1,x2,x3...] but have only managed to get the approximations to be listed vertically downwards each on a separate line

e.g.

x1

x2

x3

This is my code so far. I am new to coding so any help and advice would be much appreciated :)

```
a= float(input('enter the positive value that you wish to find the babylonian square root of '))
e= float(input('enter a positive value for maxium error '))
x= float(input('enter an arbitrary starting value '))

if a<0 or a==0:
    print(' a must be a positive number')
elif e<0 or e==0:
    print('e must be a positive number')
elif x==0:
    print('starting value cannot be 0 as cant divide by 0!')
else:
 
    
    while abs(x**2-a)>e or abs(x**2-a)==e :
        x=0.5*(x-(a/x))
        xn=0.5*(x-(a/x))
         x=xn 
   
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list and then output the list:

```
a = float(input('enter the positive value that you wish to find the babylonian square root of '))
e = float(input('enter a positive value for maxium error '))
x = float(input('enter an arbitrary starting value '))

if a < 0 or a == 0:
    print(' a must be a positive number')
elif e < 0 or e == 0:
    print('e must be a positive number')
elif x == 0:
    print('starting value cannot be 0 as cant divide by 0!')
else:
    result_list = []
    while abs(x ** 2 - a) > e or abs(x ** 2 - a) == e:
        x = 0.5 * (x - (a / x))
        xn = 0.5 * (x - (a / x))
        x = xn
        result_list.append(x)
    print(result_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried this but it only prints the empty set [] rather than the list of approximations

Comment: I just tested and got a list, what are your test values?

Comment: i was using a=64 e=0.5 x0=7 (on jupyter notebook0

Comment: I updated my answer with the full code. I tested this with the values you gave me and got an output that looks accurate